# Add logout link when logged in, make it disappear when logged out?

Tags: login, logout

I am trying to display a logout link when users are logged in and make it disappear when they are not logged in.

The code I have so far works for the login and register links due to a plugin that I have installed, so 'login' and 'register' disappear just fine, now for logout I need some assistance... Here is the code:

```
<ul id="login-navigation">
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
          $user = wp_get_current_user();
          echo 'Welcome <strong>'.$user->display_name.'!</strong> ';
} else { ?>
    <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register" class="simplemodal-register" >Register</a>
    <strong>or</strong>
<?php }
wp_loginout( get_permalink() ); ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`wp_loginout()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout). It automatically handles those conditions.

Comment: Sorry Im somewhat of a noob. How can I implement this?

Comment: put the above function wherever you want the login/logout link to appear thats it. This would show a logout link when the user is logged in and viceversa.

Comment: I changed the code how you suggested, it's above.

I made it so that it redirects to the current page but when I try to login from home it takes me to a post.

Comment: paste your updated code

Comment: Its the one in the post. That's how it looks now. See how I added <?php wp_loginout( get_permalink() ); ?>

Comment: if your homepage shows your most recent posts then get_permalink would return the link of the most recent post. You would have to put conditions for homepage, archives, search and 404

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ul id="login-navigation" >
    <?php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo __('Welcome') . ' <strong>' . $user->display_name . '!</strong> ';
    } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register') ?>" class="simplemodal-register" ><?php echo __('Register'); ?></a>
        <strong>or</strong>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_loginout( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>
</ul>
```